# pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 3, saw 11

Tags: pandas

Problem arise while I practice----K Nearest Neighbors Application - Practical Machine Learning Tutorial with Python p.14.

data information from `breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt`

```
id,clump_thickness,unif_cell_size,unif_cell_shape,marg_adhesion,single_epith_cell_size,bare_nuclei,bland_chrom,norm_nucleoli,mitoses,class
1000025,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1002945,5,4,4,5,7,10,3,2,1,2
1015425,3,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2
1016277,6,8,8,1,3,4,3,7,1,2
1017023,4,1,1,3,2,1,3,1,1,2
1017122,8,10,10,8,7,10,9,7,1,4
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation,neighbors
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt')
df.replace('?',-99999, inplace=True)
#df.drop(['id'], 1, inplace=True)

X = np.array(df.drop(['class'], 1))
y = np.array(df['class'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print(accuracy)
```

But error shows. What is wrong?